# Package for distributing calculations

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, package

Do you know of any package for distributing calculations on several computers and/or several cores on each computer? The calculation code is in c++, the package needs to be able to cope with data >2GB and work on a windows x64 machine. Shareware would be nice, but isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

A suitable solution would depend on the type of calculation and data you wish you process, the granularity of parallelism you wish to achieve, and how much effort you are willing to invest in it.

The simplest would be to just use a suitable solver/library that supports parallelism (e.g. 
[scalapack](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/)). Or if you wish to roll your own solvers, you can squeeze out some paralleisation out of your current code using [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmp) or compilers that provide automatic paralleisation (e.g Intel C/C++ compiler). All these will give you a reasonable performance boost without requiring massive restructuring of your code.

At the other end of the spectrum, you have the [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) option. It can afford you the most performance boost if your algorithm parallelises well. It will however require a fair bit of reengineering.

Another alternative would be to go down the threading route. There are libraries an tools out there that will make this less of a nightmare. These are worth a look: [Boost C++ Parallel programming library](http://www.techsanctuary.com/boost-c-parallel-programming-l) and [Threading Building Block](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

Answer (score 0):

There's an [MPI](http://www.mpi-forum.org) library and the [DVM system](http://www.keldysh.ru/dvm/dvmhtm1107/eng/index.html) working on top of MPI. These are generic tools widely used for parallelizing a variety of tasks.